# Drop down <ul> disappears on hovering on menu

Tags: css, html, drop-down-menu

I am creating a drop down menu using css only.It also has a sub menu which is nested in the <li>. When i hover on the <li> the sub menus are coming but when i am moving cursor over, it vanishes.

Please help me out this problem.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cjee/HaFu8/) Here is the fiddle link

```css
.nav-bar {
  background:#ccc;
  height:38px;
  width:100%;
}
.nav-bar .nav {
  list-style-type:none;
}
.nav li {
  float:left;
  width:auto;
  font:bold 14px/38px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;

}
.nav li a {
  padding:0 22px;
  color:#fff;
  display:block;
  text-decoration:none;
}
.nav li a:hover {
  background-color:#231f20;
  color:#66ccff;
}
.nav li  a.activemenu  {
  padding:0 22px;
  background-color:#231f20;
  color:#66ccff;
  display:block;
  text-decoration:none;
}
.nav li.spacer {
  background:url(../images/nav-spacer.jpg) left top no-repeat;
  width:2px;
  height:38px;
  padding:0;
}
.nav li span.arrow {
  margin:0;
  padding-left:5px;
  height:12px;
  font-size:11px;
}
/** sub nav **/
ul.sub-nav {
  list-style-type:none;
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  background:#f2f2f2; 
  border:solid 1px #bababa;
  border-radius:5px;
  -moz-border-radius:5px;
  padding:10px 0;
  margin-top:5px;
  box-shadow:2px 2px 2px #333;
}
ul.sub-nav li {
  float:none;
}
ul.sub-nav li a { 
  color:#333;
  text-decoration:none;
  font:normal 14px/26px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  display:block;
}
ul.sub-nav li a:hover {
  background-color:#7f7f7f;
  color:#fff;
}

.nav li:hover ul.sub-nav {
  display:block;
}
ul.sub-nav span {
  position:absolute;
  top:-24px;
  left:20px;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-bar">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Package</a></li>
    <li class="spacer"></li>                
    <li><a href="#">Investigation<span class="arrow">▼</span></a>
      <ul class="sub-nav">
        <span><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/z88Pm.png" alt="" /></span>
        <li><a href="#">Project</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Project Description</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Project Account Type</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Project Resources</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="spacer"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Messaging</a></li>
    <li class="spacer"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Billing</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you all for the reply. But the design needs the 5px margin from the main menu and sub menu. How can I do that? is that feasible in only css?

Answer (score 7):

Under `.ul.sub-nav`, margin-top is the issue. If you remove it, it will work perfectly fine.

Comment: Yeah its because of the space in between. If you followed your cursor over the tip point of the quote it still works but that added space is the problem.

Comment: Yes @Keith. The margin-top allows the space and when the mouse moves out to select the sub items, it disappears.

Comment: Yes - @gomino. You have removed the margin-top for it to work.